# Web service concurrent calls processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've faced with the next issue related to web service request processing:

**Preamble**
I have

- Web api service hosted on IIS 7.0 on local machine
- Test harness console application on the same machine

and i'm trying to simulate web service load by hitting one with requests generated via test harness app.
Test harness core code:

```
    static int HitsCount = 40;

    static async void PerformHitting()
    {
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, HitsCount)
                                                 .Select(_ => HitAsync())
                                                 .WithDegreeOfParallelism(HitsCount));
        }
    }

    static async Task HitAsync()
    {
        // some logging skipped here
        ...
        await new HttpClient().GetAsync(TargetUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    }
```

**Expectation**
Logging shows that all HitAsync() calls are made simultaneously: each hit via HttpClients had started in
[0s; 0.1s] time frame (timings are roughly rounded here and below). Hence, I'm expecting to catch all these requests in approximately the same time frame on web service side.

**Reality**
But logging on the service side shows that requests grouped in bunches 8-12 request each and service catches these bunches with ~1 second interval. I mean:

```
[0s, 0.3s] <- requests #0-#10
[1.2s, 1.6s] <- requests #10-#20
...
[4.1s, 4.5s] <- request #30-#40
```

And i'm getting really long execution time for any significant `HitCount` values.

**Question**
I suspect some kind of built-in service throttling mechanism or framework built-in concurrent connections limitation. Only I found related to such guesstimate is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849884/what-is-limiting-the-of-simultaneous-connections-my-asp-net-application-can-ma), but i didn't get any success trying soulutions from there.
Any ideas what is the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Building a load test harness is a good practice when learning how they work but its almost always more productive to use an existing tool for such a job. Check out [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) as an example (several out there).

Answer (score 1):

By default, HTTP requests on ASP.NET are limited to 12 times the number of cores. I recommend setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you for reply.     
I've tried to change value of `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` both on Test harness side and Web service side. And i can see under debug that `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` really changed but service still can catch only ~10 concurrent requests.

Comment: As long as you're setting it before the first request, you shouldn't be limited on your client side. Do you have any limits on the server side?

Comment: I set limitations on server side exatcly the same as on client side. As i can see the result is the same for limitations set like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms998549#scalenetchapt06_topic5) and for limitations like `DefaultConnectionLimit = 1`.  Setting `processModel.maxIoThreads` in `machine.config` has no any result too.  **[UPD]** I'm wrong. Setting `DefaultConnectionLimit = 1` in runtime (not in config) on server side changes the behavior: i get first 10 requests in bunch and the rest 1 pre second

Answer (score 0):

Well, the root of the problems lies in the IIS + Windows 7 concurrent requests handling limit (some info about such limits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147351/does-iis-7-have-limit-of-simultaneous-requests). Moving service out to the machine with Windows Server kicked out the problem.