# how to create a self hosting server for asp.net websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, sql-server-2008

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC5. I want to create a self hosting server for my website such that my PC would run this website for my clients.

As for Wordpress websites we use  [Desktop Server](http://serverpress.com/products/desktopserver/), what software or technique can be used for ASP.NET websites

Comment: have you consulted with a viable `ISP` you should check something like `GoDaddy` good luck trying to do this especially if you are not familiar with `Static IP's` and your local PC I truly doubt that this has the processing power of a valid Web Server.. do some googling as well

Comment: @DJKRAZE If someone is asking about a self-hosted solution, then probably best not to recommend a hosting company.

Comment: GoDaddy hosts website, i am asking for self-hosting solution, googling hasn't helped me much yet

Comment: I agree Mason but I do not think that the OP is familiar with all that is involved especially when wanting to host on their local PC..

Comment: Affuu you can host a website on your own I think that you will need to secure a static IP address as well as speak with whomever your Internet Service Provider is as well I am sure they have some support their as well

Comment: UltiDev server can host ASP.Net websites. It may only support up to MVC4 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have confused what the term "self hosted" means. Self hosted means that your application bundles its own web server with it, meaning there is no need for IIS/Apache/Nginx.

What you want to do is have a publicly accessible website at your home or business. What you need for that is a static IP address from your ISP (there are ways to do it with dynamic, but much better to use static), to configure your firewall to forward the appropriate ports to your computer (usually port 80 and 443), to configure your computer to use a static IP on your local network, make sure that you have a secure site (it's likely massively vulnerable) and to check your ISP's Terms and Conditions to make sure they'll allow you to host a site on their connection (most residential ISP services disallow it). You can use IIS on your computer, you don't have to self host it.

You'll also want a server edition of Windows to [avoid the request limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147351/does-iis-7-have-limit-of-simultaneous-requests).